# swift 3 and restkit: Cannot convert value of type '(...) -> Void' to expected argument type '(...) -> Void)!'

Tags: xcode, swift3

This is the code that used to work before swift 3:

```
manager.getObjectsAtPath(path, parameters: self.sessionParams(), success: { (operation, mappingResult) -> Void in
    // success code    
}, failure: { (operation: RKObjectRequestOperation?, error: Error?) -> Void in
    // failure code
})
```

Now I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(RKObjectRequestOperation?, Error?) ->
>   Void' to expected argument type '((RKObjectRequestOperation?, Error?)
>   -> Void)!'

How to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: The compiler wants probably `failure: { (operation: (RKObjectRequestOperation?, error: Error?) -> Void)!` as suggested in the error message.